# How to correctly configure jsoup for escape characters?

Tags: jsoup

```
<div id="virtualPath">
<a href='/'>text</a> >> 
<a href='' title=''>More text</a> >> 
<a href=''>Some text</a> >> 
<span class="boldFont">some more text</span>
</div>
```

I have html as shown above. When I use selectors I get following html.

```
<div id="virtualPath"> 
<a href="/">text</a> &gt;&gt; 
<a href="" title="">more text</a> &gt;&gt; 
<span class="boldFont">some more text</span>
</div>
```

What configuration should I use to get correct html? I understand that html is not well formed, but since the generation html is not under my control, I need to handle this issue in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [unescapeHtml](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29)-Method from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) for escaping / unescaping your html.